# OffsetDateTime object should not be converted to json object

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I am converting java object into json object. But OffsetDatetime also being converted to json format. Is it possible to keep the time object as OffsetDatetime timestamp itself.

Java object

```
{
  "start_date": "2022-01-01T13:45:00+01:00",
  "origin": {
    "type": "AIRPORT",
    "search_display_name": "Malmo, Sweden (MMX-Sturup)",
    "search_string": "MMX",
    "city": "Malmo"
  }
}
```

After converting to json, getting as follows

```
{
  "start_date": {
    "offset": {
      "total_seconds": 0,
      "id": "Z",
      "rules": {
        "fixed_offset": true,
        "transition_rules": [
          
        ],
        "transitions": [
          
        ]
      }
    },
    "day_of_month": 1,
    "day_of_week": "SATURDAY",
    "day_of_year": 1,
    "month": "JANUARY",
    "month_value": 1,
    "year": 2022,
    "hour": 12,
    "minute": 45,
    "nano": 0,
    "second": 0
  },
  "origin": {
    "search_display_name": "Malmo, Sweden (MMX-Sturup)",
    "search_string": "MMX",
    "city": "Malmo"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to keep offsetDateTime like this "2022-01-01T13:45:00+01:00"

Java object will be converted to json using this method `objectMapper.valueToTree(response)`
Object mapper configuration as follows

```
@Bean("objectMapperJavaTime")
public ObjectMapper objectMapperJavaTime() {
    return JacksonObjectMapperFactory.createMapperWithDefaultConfigurations()
             .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
             .enable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE);
}


public class JacksonObjectMapperFactory {

    public static ObjectMapper createMapperWithDefaultConfigurations(){
          return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
                          .featuresToDisable(WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                            .failOnUnknownProperties(false)
                            .serializationInclusion(NON_NULL)
                            .propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE)
                            .modules(new JodaModule())
                            .build();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's easily doable, but how are you converting the object to JSON? Please edit the question to show your relevant code. It might be as simple as overriding the function to simply return a string rather than the whole serialized object.

Comment: @sorifiend Thanks for looking into it. I have edited the question

Comment: @sorifiend tried disabling this feature WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS. But still it is not working.

Comment: The bean was not picked up initially. It has been resolved now after disabling this feature.Thank you @sorifiend

Answer (score 1):

Often there are issues attempting to disable the `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` feature on creation like that.

So the solution is not to apply the featrue on creation, so remove this:

```
.featuresToDisable(WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)....
```

And instead of setting feature and returning the objectMapper on one line, you can break it up and set the feature to false after the ObjectMapper has been created:

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);`
```

Then return the objectMapper.

Comment: I tried to add WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS feature on object mapper. But it did not work. Still i am not getting date as "start_date": "2022-01-01T13:45:00+01:00".   @Bean("objectMapperJavaTime")
public ObjectMapper objectMapperJavaTime() {
   return EgenciaJacksonObjectMapperFactory.createMapperWithDefaultConfigurations().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
         .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
         .disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
}

Comment: I have overridden  this feature WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS in objectMapperJavaTime() since JacksonObjectMapperFactory this class is a library and it is not owned by our team